# data-disqus-url to get comment count

Tags: disqus

I have 2 different html tags like this:

```
<span class="count-comments"
 data-disqus-url="http://abcd.com/?r=front/page&p=body-thought&idartikel=123">
 No comment
</span>
```

and the second one like this:

```
<span class="count-comments"
 data-disqus-url="http://www.abcd.com/?r=front/page&p=body-thought&idartikel=123">
 No comment
</span>
```

I want to get comment count from disqus.
I found that with the first way I can get the comment count.
While with the second way I can not get the comment count.

And the real url where visitor can submit comment is the url in the second way. (with www. ).

While on another case (on some other page within the same domain), the opposite is happening. The second way get comment count and the first way can not get comment count.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

By providing `data-disqus-url`, you're telling Disqus to look up the comment count for that exact URL. A URL with 'www.' is actually distinct from URLs without it, so essentially the second request is unable to find a thread with that link.

You have a few options to fix this:

1. Choose a domain for your site (with or without the 'www.') and redirect from one to the other. This is generally best practice for any site, regardless of whether Disqus is on it.
2. If all of your Disqus comment threads use the non-www. domain, make sure `data-disqus-url` always excludes the www., regardless of the page it's on.
3. Use a custom `disqus_identifier` for your threads, and then use `data-disqus-identifier` for your comment count links instead of `data-disqus-url`. See here for more: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472099

Comment: ryan_v, thank you for the answer. I found my own solution before read your solution. My solution is adding `#disqus_thread` to the end of href value of <a> tag. And that solution give consistent comment count whether I use url with WWW or without WWW.